# Customise drop shadow size (larger) in Preview.app

Tags: macos, catalina, preview

In Preview you can draw shapes.

You can add a drop shadow to these shapes.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to make the drop shadow larger.

On the scale of the image I am annotating, the drop shadow just looks like a tiny black border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preview doesn't support this.

I solved it by drawing a square inside of a fully transparent image, adding the drop shadow, saving it, closing it, reopening it, then rotating and resizing the drop shadow until it fit my needs and copy/pasting it into my original document.